# Complex Digamma Function

Tags: c++, function, math

Do you know a c++ library where the **Digamma Function** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) is implemented with complex arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find a library, but google found this for me:

[GammaFunctions.c++](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~lunevill/doc_melina++_v039/src/special_functions/GammaFunctions.c++.html)

However I did not check the validity of this code.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

- [GSL - GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) contains `gsl_sf_complex_psi_e`.
- http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~lunevill/doc_melina++_v039/src/special_functions/GammaFunctions.c++.html
- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/978-special-functions-math-library/content/psi.m - You'll need to convert this to C++.
- http://www.netlib.no/netlib/slatec/fnlib/cpsi.f - You'll need to convert this to C++.